# Reverse Image Searching a ChemDraw Figure

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-structure

Is there any image-recognition software out there that can read in a high-resolution image of a ChemDraw-generated figure and back out the structure (such as the SMILES or INChI)? I have a bunch of review papers where there are tables upon tables of ChemDraw images of molecules and would really like to put them into some useable database.

Comment: You can try this http://chemdataextractor.org/
If you manage to obtain something, I'd kindly ask you to post the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best tool I have come across so far to do this is this one: https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/osra/
I was also reading about this other [one](https://bulletin.acscinf.org/PDFs/247nm51.pdf), but can't find the link to the tool itself.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new tool for this: [pic2mol.com](https://pic2mol.com/). It's a cloud-based optical structure recognition service and an add-in for ChemDraw. There is a free trial. If you have ChemOffice, you can give it a try.

**Disclaimer**: I am affiliated with pic2mol.

Comment: I guess it you have a chemdraw object, you could convert it to SMILES, which was the objective of the question. While this is probably not the most convenient way of doing it, I accept this answer as a possible way to do this, and therefore regard this post as an answer (on the technicalities of what is an answer).