# Convert an image of a chemical structure to a ChemDraw file?

Tags: molecular-structure

Is there a way to convert a bitmap (JPG, PNG) image of a chemical structure to a ChemDraw file so that you don't have to draw a structure you find in a paper yourself?

Comment: In short, yes. But I don't know of a program that does this. Also, it would not be simple, since it would require features to identify perspective and depth (to disentangle overlaping features), all far from trivial. But for simple molecules you may be able to write your own script.

Comment: You question immediately brought two terms in my mind: "chemical" and "OCR" (Optical Character Recognition). You should Google "Optical OCR" and you will find some interesting resources.

Comment: You would probably need to train a machine learning algorithm. Also SMILES would likely be an easier output, which you can convert into a ChemDraw file trivially anyway. I think it would be a fun side project, although the benefits are perhaps not commensurate with the required effort...

Comment: I asked the same question (https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/103229/reverse-image-searching-a-chemdraw-figure) a few months back with little in the way of answers, unfortunately. Hopefully there is more luck here.

Comment: Mathpix (https://mathpix.com/blog/convert-image-to-chemdraw) claims to do it. Costs $ (not much, free educational usage), have never used it, just showed up in a Google query, and any other disclaimers I've forgotten about...

Comment: There is a new tool for this: [pic2mol.com](https://pic2mol.com/). It's a cloud-based optical structure recognition service and an add-in for ChemDraw. Like Mathpix it is also paid, but there is a free trial available. If you have ChemOffice, you can give it a try. **Disclaimer**: I am affiliated with pic2mol.